Roku ECP commands does nothing
We faced the following issue. There is a test written from appium and Roku app. It worked for some time for two Roku devices, but one day it stopped working without changes in code on device 2. The ECP commands stopped working. For example, any button press HTTP commands respond with 200 code, but the app does not receive any of them on device 2.
Moreover, "roku: activeApp" command started responding with HTTP 500. At the same time the test still works against device 1.
May be someone can suggest something. Because we run out of ideas.
I saw a post in the forum that it's possible that Roku can block dev mode on some devices (not sure if it's related).

related? https://blog.roku.com/developer/addressing-current-ecp-issues-our-developer-are-experiencing

It come that it somehow blocked by account. When resetting the device and using the same account, it still does not work. When resetting the device and using another account it works. So, seems Roku monitors the activity and blocks devices. I saw a post in the forum where one developer with 100+ devices was blocked on all of them, seems due to building apps and distributing directly (running on a device in dev mode instead of posting the app to the store).

If it's working on one device but not on another I would suggest the next steps for the 'not-working' device:

Check if Developer mode is enabled and if needed enable it back: It's
possible that Developer Mode got disabled on the problematic device.
You can re-enable it by following these steps:
On your Roku remote, press Home -> Home -> Home -> Up -> Up -> Right
-> Left -> Right -> Left -> Right. Follow the on-screen instructions to enable Developer Mode.

Check your network: Ensure both devices are on the same network and there are no firewall rules or other network configurations
blocking the ECP commands.

Factory Reset: As a last resort, you could perform a factory reset on the problematic device. This will erase all data and return
the device to its original settings. You can do this from the Roku's
system settings.


Let me know if it helps.
